# Rendering Full-blown HTML in SSRS 2008 (not just tags)

Tags: html, reporting-services, report

Is it possible to render other forms of HTML syntax besides basic tags for rich text in SSRS 2008?

If I create an expression which is an HTML placeholder, SSRS successfully renders the basic tags like "b", "i", "p", "br", and other rich-text-oriented tags.  But if I want to do something like embed an image from a URL or create a table using HTML, then that bit of HTML simply will not be rendered.  The report does not fail to run though; it just ignores that bit of HTML.

Perhaps full HTML support in an SSRS 2008 report is obtainable through some other means besides an HTML placeholder expression.  I looked into using some other type of report element besides a textbox for more HTML support, but see none available.

Comment: I've posted this on MS Connect, please vote it up: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1019539/support-additional-html-tags-in-ssrs-2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is no. Officially, only a handful are supported. I've searched high and low for other tag support (specifically  support), and it among others is not supported.
The following tags are supported:

Hyperlinks: <A href>
Fonts: <FONT>
Header, style and block elements: <H{n}>, <DIV>, <SPAN>,<P>, <DIV>, <LI>, <HN>
Text format: <B>, <I>, <U>, <S>
List handling: <OL>, <UL>, <LI>

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx)